# Load label and img using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

In code below i want when a thumbnail image in repeater clicked the fullsize img and the title of image load in leftDiv...i have a row in my db table "paintingTitle" for the title of each image...
the img is loading properly but i don't know how add label to this javascript code...
i'm new in javascript...
i want my label right after the img in photoHolder div...

```html
        <div id="mainDiv">
            <div id="leftDiv">
                <div id="photoHolder">
                    <img src="Images/fullsize/E1.jpg" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightDiv">
                <div id="sideWall">
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="paintingsSds" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EilyaCString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [paintingsTbl]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="paintingsRpt" runat="server" DataSourceID="paintingsSds"> 
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img src='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "thumbnailUrl")%>' full='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "fullsizeUrl")%>'/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                    <script language="JavaScript">
                        $('#sideWall img').click(function () {
                            $this = $(this);
                            $image = $this.attr('full');
                            $("#photoHolder").hide().html('<img src="' + $image + '" />').fadeIn(2000);
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Where do you want label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your HTML and add label as required.

*HTML*

```
<div id="photoHolder">
    <img src="Images/fullsize/E1.jpg" />
    <label>Some text</label>
</div>
```

*Script*

```
var _placeHolder = $("#photoHolder").hide();
_placeHolder.find('img').prop('src', $image); //To change image URL
_placeHolder.find('label').text('New Text');  //To change label text
_placeHolder.fadeIn(2000);
```